# Why .apk file is not running on the real device

Tags: android

I have developed an Android app. That app is running on the emulator perfectly. My application gets data from webservices. when I run the applicaton on a real device, I am getting force close.
I do not understand what the reason is. I came to know that we can debug our application by running on real device. I don't know exactly how to do it.
I found some link for using a real device for debugging http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html. But in this link it is given that usbdrivers are required for connecting the device to a PC. I am using Samsung Galaxy y . I did not found any drivers for that model (GT-S5360). Can anybody please help me.

Comment: Have you installed Samsung kies? If you've means, then make sure this. Settings -> Applications -> Development - Enable USB Debugging

Comment: yes after you install the kies which will install the drivers necessary you need to go into your phone and enable usb debugging and also allow unknown sources. you also need a debug flag set in your manifest file. these are all easy to find via searching google, then simply plug your phone in and when you run your application in eclipse you will have your phone available to test on. also make sure your phones api level is the same or greater as your app.

Answer (score 2):

Except from device debugging you can also have a look at the device generated log. There are many applications that allows you to do do, [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=en) being one.

Comment: Emailing the log file to myself is a great timesaver when troubleshooting on the device.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the **Android SDK**.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Activate **USB Debugging** on your device and run `adb logcat` in a command line on the host.

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/

If you use eclipse, you can do all this the same way as on the emulator.

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-eclipse.html